# TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState') on NextJs Page Router but not happening in NextJs App Router

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, package, tsup

I'm trying to create a simple useState React hook library using tsup bundler and the usage example using both NextJs App Router and Page Router. I have tried using the library inside the App Router and it is working fine, but when I tried to use it on Page Router, it returns the error of

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'useState')
```

Repository link: https://github.com/elianrichard/simple-react-package

## Steps to reproduce

```bash
git clone https://github.com/elianrichard/simple-react-package.git
cd simple-react-package
npm install
npm run build
```

App Router

```bash
npm --prefix ./example/nextjs-app-router install
npm --prefix ./example/nextjs-app-router run dev
```

Page Router

```bash
npm --prefix ./example/nextjs-page-router install
npm --prefix ./example/nextjs-page-router run dev
```

I have tried to delete the `node_modules` inside the library directory, but the error still exists. I'm really confused where I went wrong, you can see all of the config inside the repo. Thankyou!

Answer (score 0):

```
import React from "react";

export default function useNewState() {
  const [state, setState] = React.useState(0);

  return {
    state,
    setState,
  };
}
```

based on your code u have write the useState but not using just returing it which is not corrct
you must do like that

```
  import React from "react";

export default function MyComponent() {
  // Call the useNewState hook to initialize state
  const { state, setState } = useNewState(0);

  // Event handler to update state
  const handleClick = () => {
    setState(prevState => prevState + 1); // Increment state by 1
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Current State: {state}</p>
      <button onClick={handleClick}>Increment State</button>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**setState** this value to use to store the data
**state** this data is used to get the sotored value

Comment: Nope, the problem still persist. Did you try to clone this and run it locally?